# How to connect Orion Context Broker with SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, fiware, fiware-orion, crate

Is there any way to send the entities from Orion Context Broker to SQL Server by using docker compose file?

Right now, Orion subscribes to the entities and Quantum Leap notifies the Crate DB when there is a change for those entities. However, Crate DB is not what I want and this is the reason: https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Direct-Query-for-PostgreSQL/m-p/776979/highlight/true#M374297

So basically my question is, if there is any way to replace the Crate DB with any of these supported ones: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-directquery-data-sources. 
(I randomly chose the SQL Server but any other is fine)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Quantum Leap or CrateDB but, basically, you could create a Context Consumer to receive notifications from Orion (a subscription would be created for that) so each notification is persisted in your target DB (in this case SQL Server).

In fact, maybe you can take advantage of [Cygnus](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-cygnus) instead of developing that piece of software from scratch. Cygnus is extensible and there is [documentation about how to extend it](https://fiware-cygnus.readthedocs.io/en/master/cygnus-ngsi/user_and_programmer_guide/adding_new_sink/index.html), so new sinks can be developed. You need to develop the sink for SQL Server. Note that there already sinks for other SQL-based databases (MySQL and Postgresql in particular) so they could be a good starting point.

If at the end you develop a new sink, it would be a great contribution to Cygnus catalog of sinks. Please, don't hesitate to send as the pull request in that